# How to present view controller modally using a tab bar controller SWIFT iOS

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to present a view controller modally from tapping a tab bar button.

I was advised to use the tab bar delegate functions

Where would I place the tab bar delegate functions? In the AppDelegate file?

Also what fun would I use to actually present the view controller. So instead of the tab bar switching the main view to the view controller I would like it to present the view controller modally instead.